# Java Tokenization with Gradle

Tags: java, security, gradle

For my current project, I'm working on connecting to a MySQL database using Java.

I have a bit of code, in which I'm using Gradle to substitute sensitive database credentials into the .java file using ReplaceTokens to populate a new version of the file in the build directory and source that version (with the replaced "detokenized" values) to compile the .class file.

I do not anticipate anyone aside from the core dev team handling the source .java files, only the .war which contains the compiled .class files. However, from a peek at these .class files using vim, I can tell that the detokenized values are plainly visible in the compiled bytecode.

My question is, **assuming a scenario in which my .class files could be retrieved from the server by a potentially malicious agent, is there any better method of tokenization that would give another layer of security to the database credentials?**

For additional information, the MySQL DB is accessed through a socket only, so I do not expect a malicious agent could do anything with the DB credentials alone, but I would like to make it as difficult as possible to determine these credentials anyway.

Thank you for any advice! I'm still very new to Java and Gradle in general, but this project has already given me much insight into what can be done.

Comment: Pass the values as encrypted strings and then decrypt in your runtime

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you for the suggestion! Do you have an example, link or otherwise, of what this encrypt/decrypt implementation would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some simple code that does base64 encoding / decoding

I am using `Blowfish` for the `algo`

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public static String encrypt(String text) throws Exception
{
    SecretKeySpec sksSpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algo );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
    cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sksSpec);

    byte[] encrypt_bytes = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    return new String( Base64.encodeBase64(encrypt_bytes) );
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypt_str) throws Exception
{
    SecretKeySpec sksSpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algo);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sksSpec);

    return new String(cipher.doFinal( Base64.decodeBase64(encrypt_str.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this implementation example! I will study it and see if I can adapt something similar to my needs.